# Why do we need .so.1 file in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, dynamic-linking

In Linux, for shared libraries, I usually see .so, .so.1 and .so.1.0 files of one library. For example, library test should be presented by libtest.so libtest.so.1 libtest.so.1.0 files.
As my understand, .so.1.0 contains real data; .so is linked to .so.1.0 and is used in linking.
But I don't understand the purpose of .so.1 file.
Could someone clarify the use of .so.1 file?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Version numbers in shared object files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760111/version-numbers-in-shared-object-files)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Let's say we are talking about `libtest`. If you look around, you'll see `libtest.so`, which is a link to `libtest.so.1`, which in turn links to `libtest.so.1.5`.

An executable using `libtest` will link against `libtest.so` which is `libtest.so.1` in this case (this is written into the executable, see `ldd(1)`). If your distribution changes `libtest` to fix bugs, the new version might give `libtest.so.1.6` (and after update `libtest.so.1` links to it, running programs will still use `libtest.so.1.5` until they exit). As long as no ABI changes are made, everything works fine. And the fact that there are no API changes is signalled by the unchanged 1 version number.

Let's say the busy `libtest` beavers come up with a new, all shiny, rewritten from scratch library, with changed ABI. As the ABI changed, they change the major version number to 2. You install that one, and now you have the chain `libtest.so --> libtest.so.2 --> libtest.so.2.1`. Note you have now both versions 1 and 2 installed. Your earlier programs still work fine, using `libtest.so.1`, but if you compile a new program the compiler (linker, really) will pick up `libtest.so` and thus point the executable at the new `libtest.so.2.1` (unless specifically asked to use the old version, that is).

Note that the so version numbers don't need to have any relationship to the source code version numbers; the major number is ABI version, the minor number is optional and can be used to track revisions. So here (Fedora 20) I'm using `systemd-libs-208-15.fc20.x86_64`, which provides `libsystemd-daemon.so.0.0.10`.

Answer (score 3):

These are different versions of the same library.

Normally, you want the most recent stable version of the library, so you link to x.so, which is linked to that most recent version. When a new version becomes available, say x.so.2, you can make your whole system use it, by linking x.so to x.so.2

Sometimes you want to link to an old version - for example if your program relies on a quirk that's been fixed, or the latest version has introduced a bug. Sometimes you want to link to a new experimental version - for example if you're testing it, or if it fixes a bug in the current version. In that case you would link directly to the numbered version - hopefully as a temporary measure.