# my files linking to libGL.so.1

Tags: c++, opengl

okay so i am not sure whether this is happening accordingly , but when i use g++ my files seem to link to libGL.so.1

here is part of the the output when i run ldd

```
ldd a.out 
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff151fe000)
libGLEW.so.1.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.10     (0x00007f86d4242000)
libglfw.so.3 => /usr/lib/libglfw.so.3 (0x00007f86d4028000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f86d3cf8000)
```

now when i search for my libGL.so file it finds that as well in the same directory /usr/lib/x86....../libGL.so

now my question is why is it linking to ...so.1 and not the libGL.so

i also seem to have mesa-dev libraries installed but i want to make sure that my GL links are made to the graphics driver and not the mesa libraries do i need to uninstall the mesa drivers and re-link the libraries here?

do i need to remove the libgl1-mesa* files? are they needed when i have my graphics card drivers installed?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760111/version-numbers-in-shared-object-files (in my understanding the libGL.so should be a symbolic link to libGL.so.1 - you can check with ls -l /path/to/libGL.so ).

Comment: i just did that check and it gave me this:

ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jul  3 16:28 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so -> mesa/libGL.so

why is it pointing to mesa? shouldnt it be pointing to my graphics card drivers?

Comment: i just threw in my 5 cents :-) cant help no more... ( isn't opengl a "specification" and "mesa" a conforming implementaiton of openGl? )

Comment: i also have the same file libGL.so which is not in the mesa folder 

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so

how do i make libGL.so.1 link to it?

Comment: @hopjoppe5: Please don't! Don't touch those intricate link chains if you don't exactly know what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

`ldd` shows you what a program *effectively* links to. Not which file or library has been given at compile time. Shared objects have something called a *soname*, which is kind of a versioning system. When your program got linked against `libGL.so` the linker extracted from the particular specimen that was used, that the soname in fact was `libGL.so.1` and put that name into your program binary.

At runtime the dynamic linker `ld.so` looks in a whole range of directories for a shared object that matches this soname. The list of directories can be configured, see `man ld.so` and `man ldconfig`.

Now `libGL.so` is a tricky beast. It usually ships as part of the graphics drivers. For Linux there are several driver packages around:

- Mesa, the open source OpenGL implementation and drivers
- NVidia's proprietary blob
- AMD's proprietary blob

However on systems with GPUs from different vendors things get trickier; there's no formally specified ICD mechanism on Linux. But there exist (quite a few) libGL.so dispatchers/proxies which take a look at the graphics environment a process has been started in and load the appropriate vendor libGL.so from there. The usual implementation is that a small helper program is started, that uses GLX transport to create a indirect OpenGL context, read the OpenGL version strings and returns the path to the actual libGL.so the be used. This works, because the GLX modules in the X server have their relationship to the OpenGL implementation hardcoded and GLX can be be talked without the need for libGL.so (see for example the GLX module in Xcb).

In general you should not mess with the shared objects in your system if you don't know what you're doing. Just link your programs with `-lGL` and the linker will take it from there.