# cc compiler can't find link library in provided path

Tags: c++, makefile, cc

I am trying to link against the Tensorflow library. Here is my makefile:

```
TF_PATH=/home/wade/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow
CFLAGS=-I$(TF_PATH)/include/ -L$(TF_PATH)/
CC=cc

artifaction : artifaction.o     
    $(CC) -o artifaction artifaction.o $(CFLAGS) -ltensorflow_cc

artifaction.o :
    $(CC) -c artifaction.cc $(CFLAGS)
```

Located in `$(TF_PATH)/` is `libtensorflow_cc.so.2`. I want to link against this shared library, so I provided `cc` with `-L$(TF_PATH)/`. Currently, I get this error:

```bash
cc -o artifaction artifaction.o -I/home/wade/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/include/ -L/home/wade/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/ -ltensorflow_cc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltensorflow_cc: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:7: artifaction] Error 1
```

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
TF Version: 2.15.

I'm using `cc` here, but the same error occurs with `g++` and `clang`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Isn't a `.cc` file a C++ file?  If so you should not use `cc` (the C compiler) when you compile and link your code.  You should be using `c++` (the C++ compiler).

Comment: @MadScientist the same error occurs when using g++ or clang.

Comment: Does either of `libtensorflow_cc.a` and `libtensorflow_cc.so` exist in `/home/wade/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow`?

Comment: @273K The only `.so` or `.a` which exists in that directory are `libtensorflow_cc.so.2` and `libtensorflow_framework.so.2`. I have tried linking against the latter but to no success either.

Comment: Nevertheless, you should be using `c++` if you're compiling C++ code.  The linker will look for `libX.a` or `libX.so`.  It will not go looking for `libX.so` plus random extensions like `.2`.  Usually the way things work is you create a symlink `libX.so` pointing to whichever version of the shared library you want to be linked against.  I don't know why the TF installation doesn't do that for you: usually that symlink is created as part of the install.

Comment: Use -Wl,--verbose command line argument to see what your linker is trying to do.

Comment: So it missing libtensorflow_cc.so that should be a symbolic link to libtensorflow_cc.so.2, this is because `/home/wade/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow` is not a developer package.

Comment: @MadScientist I did as you instructed and created the symlink, and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @237K You're probably right about that, this TF version was installed by pip. Is there a problem with using this library? I tried building from source but ran into some problems I couldn't solve.

Comment: IDK. `pip` with `--pre` might do that but it installs instable versions.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

The linker will *always* look for either a `lib<name>.so` or `lib<name>.a`. If the library has a extension like `.so.2`, then the linker won't be able to find the library. The solution is to create a `symlink` using the `ln` command that will redirect the linker to the `.so` you want.

Another solution is to insert a colon after the `-l` flag. This tells the compiler to use the provided name without adding `lib` or `so`. So you could do `-l:libtensorflow.so.2`.

In my case, I ran `ln -s libtensorflow_cc.so.2 libtensorflow_cc.so` and `ln -s libtensorflow_framework.so.2 libtensorflow.so`, and then the linker was able to find the libs.

Comment: `.so.2` this is not a weird extension. See [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475/how-do-so-shared-object-numbers-work), [2](https://superuser.com/questions/299009/what-do-the-number-suffixes-in-linux-dynamic-libraries-mean), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760111/version-numbers-in-shared-object-files)